# Removing items from list

Tags: python, list

I have two sequences that I want to put into a list of (x, y) coordinates.

```
seq1 = "11-345"
seq2 = "122--5"
```

I want to remove any (x, y) pair that contains a '-' so I wrote a simple for loop, but it doesn't remove all of the pairs. If there are multiple '-'s next to each other, some are not removed.

```
z = zip(seq1, seq2)
for (x, y) in z:
    if x == '-' or y == '-':
        z.remove((x, y))
```

In this example, it gives me `z = [('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('3', '-'), ('5', '5')]`
Sometimes only the first is removed, sometimes the last, depending on the sequence. Any ideas as to why or how to fix this?

Comment: Modifying a list while iterating over it is a really bad move. Try `z = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(seq1, seq2) if x != '-' and y != '-']` (and see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Cool, that works great. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentLaufer what on earth are you doing?

Comment: @KatieJ: I assume your desired result for the given input data is `[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('5', '5')]`. You should mention that explicitly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To increase performance, you can use both list comprehension and an iterator instead of a list of tuples

```
from itertools import izip
z = [ (x, y) for x, y in izip(seq1, seq2) if x != "-" and y != "-" ]
```

Comment: must be if x != "-" or y != "-"

Comment: @DamiánMontenegro no, the OP wants them removed if *either* is a `'-'`.

Comment: I don't believe so. This checks and makes sure that neither is a dash. Another option would be x == "-" or    y == "-", but they're logically equivalent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, my fault. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You miss one because you're modifying the list in the middle of iterating over it. The iterator moves from index 2 to index 3 just as you delete index 2, moving the element at 3 into position 2, which you just passed. If you print as you go, you can see it skip `(3, '-')` and `(5, 5)` because you delete the element directly before them:

```
for (x,y) in z:
  print(x, y)
  if x == '-' or y == '-':
    z.remove((x, y))

('1', '1')
('1', '2')
('-', '2')
('4', '-')
```

Using list comprehension to create a new list instead avoids the problem.

```
for z in [(x, y) for x, y in zip(seq1, seq2) if x != '-' and y != '-']:
  print z

('1', '1')
('1', '2')
('5', '5')
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the slice notation that creates a copy of the whole array:

```
seq1 = "11-345"
seq2 = "122--5"

z = zip(seq1, seq2)
for (x, y) in z[:]:
    if x == '-' or y == '-':
        z.remove((x, y))
```

Comment: That works, but making a copy of the list `z` to iterate over is a little wasteful.